# Question about inconsistency between tensorflow lite quantization code, paper and documentation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05877) paper (*Quantization and Training of Neural Networks for Efficient Integer-Arithmetic-Only Inference*) published by google, quantization scheme is described as follows:

> [image: tf-lite quantization scheme]

Where,

> M = S<sub>1</sub> * S<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>3</sub>

S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub> and S<sub>3</sub> are scales of inputs and output respectively.

Both S<sub>1</sub> (and zero point Z<sub>1</sub>) and S<sub>2</sub> (and zero point Z<sub>2</sub>) can be determined easily, whether "offline" or "online". But what about S<sub>3</sub> (and zero point Z<sub>3</sub>)? These parameters are dependent on "actual" output scale (i.e., the `float` value without quantization). But output scale is unknown before it is computed.

According to the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#dynamic_range_quantization):

> At inference, weights are converted from 8-bits of precision to floating point and computed using floating-point kernels. This conversion is done once and cached to reduce latency.

But the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/813ef350aa2858a8764d318ef521d97dd62c5859/tensorflow/lite/kernels/fully_connected.cc#L419-L433) below says something different:

```cpp
  tensor_utils::BatchQuantizeFloats(
      input_ptr, batch_size, input_size, quant_data, scaling_factors_ptr,
      input_offset_ptr, params->asymmetric_quantize_inputs);
  for (int b = 0; b < batch_size; ++b) {
    // Incorporate scaling of the filter.
    scaling_factors_ptr[b] *= filter->params.scale;
  }

  // Compute output += weight * quantized_input
  int32_t* scratch = GetTensorData<int32_t>(accum_scratch);
  tensor_utils::MatrixBatchVectorMultiplyAccumulate(
      filter_data, num_units, input_size, quant_data, scaling_factors_ptr,
      batch_size, GetTensorData<float>(output), /*per_channel_scale=*/nullptr,
      input_offset_ptr, scratch, row_sums_ptr, &data->compute_row_sums,
      CpuBackendContext::GetFromContext(context));
```

Here we can see:

```cpp
  scaling_factors_ptr[b] *= filter->params.scale;
```

I think this means:

1. S<sub>1</sub> * S<sub>2</sub> is computed.
2. The weights are still integers. Just the final results are floats.
3. It seems S<sub>3</sub> and Z<sub>3</sub> don't have to be computed. But if so, how can the final float results be close to the unquantized results?

This inconsistency between paper, documentation and code makes me very confused. I can't tell what I miss. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. All of a sudden I saw what I missed when I was
riding bicycle. The code in the question above is from the function
`tflite::ops::builtin::fully_connected::EvalHybrid()`. Here the
name has explained everything! Value in the output of matrix multiplication is
denoted as r<sub>3</sub> in section 2.2 of the paper. In terms of equation
(2) in section 2.2, we have:

> [image]

If we want to get the float result of matrix multiplication, we can use equation (4) in section 2.2, then convert the result back to floats, OR we can use equation (3) with the left side replaced with r<sub>3</sub>, as in:

> [image]

If we choose all the zero points to be `0`, then the formula above becomes:

> [image]

And this is just what `EvalHybrid()` does (ignoring the bias for the moment). Turns out the paper gives an outline of the quantization algorithm, while the implementation uses different variants.